# Customs rules in Canada about importing food

Tags: canada, regulations, food-and-drink

I want to bring in tea bags into Canada from a main supplier fully sealed, so my friend can try different types of British tea. Are there any restrictions on bringing things like tea bags and also loose leaf tea?

How about food products such as chocolate and other sweet (candy) products? I want to bring some for my friends to try and don't want to pay a fortune in shipping prices.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Canadian Food Inspection Agency](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/travellers/what-can-i-bring-into-canada-/eng/1389648337546/1389648516990) in the section *Products allowed into Canada from countries other than the United States* you are Ok bringing herbs, spices and tea, so your bags and leaves of tea should not be a problem. About candies it says you can bring up to 20Kg, which should also be enough, right?

Be advised that these requirements may be adjusted at any time because pest and disease situations are constantly changing. Even though some items are allowed into Canada, you still must declare them on your declaration form, and some provincies have their own regulations. I suggest you take a look at the link I provided and read all information.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally brought tea and sweets (and other food products) into Canada more than once from Europe.  You will have no problem at all bringing them in.